# Função que abre determinado endereço acrescentando valor do input

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um input e gostaria que ao clicar em Buscar ou enter abrisse um determinado endereço acrescentando o valor do input:
Exemplo

```html
<form align="center" method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Faça sua pergunta" autofocus name="query" size="50">
    <input  type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Buscar">
</form>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var query = document.getElementsByName('query'); 
        window.open("http://leituracrista.com/indice/?query=" + query.value);
        
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eu respondi no seu post anterior... tenta utilizar o **target** e o **method GET**.

```
<form align="center" method="GET" target="_blank>


     <input type="text" placeholder="Faça sua pergunta" autofocus name="query" size="16" style="font-size: 11 pt; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-variant: small-; border: 1 solid #000000">
     </font></font> <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"> 
     <input  type="submit" value="Buscar"  style="font-size: 8 pt; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-variant: small-caps; border: 1 solid #000000">

</form>
```

se quiser saber mais sobre: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

o que você quer fazer no caso é:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var query = document.getElementsByName('query')[0];
  window.open("http://leituracrista.com/indice/?query=" + query.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: SylvioT não serve, pois deste modo a cada pesquisa abre uma nova janela, o que quero é poder compartilhar este form de modo que possa ser inserido em qualquer site que desejar, sem a necessidade de compartilhar todo o arquivo html, mas apenas o botão de busca, entendeu?
mas de qualquer forma obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Isso resolve? 
`var query = document.getElementsByName('query')[0];`
`window.open("http://leituracrista.com/indice/?query=" + query.value);`

Comment: testando e já lhe retorno

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!